# Preferences summary is not updated when setting it's value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferencefragment

I have a Settings activity with PreferenceFragment containing settings of my app. I want to have every preference's value as it's summary so the user can see the value of each preference.
In preferences.xml I have defined 3 preferences. One is for server IP, second is for server port and third is an intent that opens external app (Barcode reader) to scan QR code which contains this IP and port. In *onActivityResult* I get the QR content, I parse it and I set those values to defaultSharedPreferences under the same key as set in preferences.xml, like that:

```
String[] scannedValues = parseQRCode(qrContent);
String serverAddr = scannedValues[0];
String port = scannedValues[1];

sharedPreferences.edit()
    .putString(Keys.KEY_PREF_SERVER, serverAddr)
    .putString(Keys.KEY_PREF_PORT, port)
    .commit();

initSummary(findPreference(Keys.KEY_PREF_SERVER));
initSummary(findPreference(Keys.KEY_PREF_PORT));
```

Now I have a method that updates all preferences summaries with their values, like that:

```
private void initSummary(Preference p) {
    if (p instanceof PreferenceGroup) {
        PreferenceGroup group = (PreferenceGroup) p;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < group.getPreferenceCount() ; i++) 
            initSummary(group.getPreference(i));
    } 
    else 
        updatePrefSummary(p);
}
private void updatePrefSummary(Preference p) {
    if (p instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) p;
        p.setSummary(editTextPref.getText()); //text still contains old value (or it is not updated on the view)
    }
}
```

In *onCreate()* method I also call *initSummary(getPreferenceScreen())* for updating all summaries with their values (only EditTextPreferences in this case) - that works well. But when I call this method after commiting those scanned values to defaultSharedPreferences, the values are not updated on the screen. BUT when I hit Back and open this activity again, I see those new values correctly updated in summaries. So they are stored correctly but they are not updated on the screen immediately after scanning the QR which I want by calling *initSummary(serverPref/portPref)* in *onActivityResult()*.

Am I missing something? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe, using EventBus, fire the event to all subscribers to inform that the changes were made, or listen in on the `onResume` of the activity upon hitting back, to reload the sharedpreference settings., or use an interface and implement it, from the editorpreferences, invoke the interface callback to those who implemented that interface and reload the sharedpreferences.

Comment: PreferenceFragment class doesn't have `onResume()` method... what do you mean by "reload sharedpreferences"? I don't understand the interface you've described

Comment: Am referring to the activity you go back to, with regards to the `onResume`.